# Is it easy to retrieve message and encryption key from several encryptions of the same message?

Tags: php, encryption, libsodium, sodium

Let's suppose the following context in php:

- A string: `$string= "my beautiful and unique string"`
- An encoding key: `$key= "mybinaryencodingkey"`
- Encryption of the string several times, for example in a php function like this:

`$encrypted_1 = sodium_crypto_secretbox($string, "nonce1", $key);`

`$encrypted_2 = sodium_crypto_secretbox($string, "nonce2", $key);`

`$encrypted_3 = sodium_crypto_secretbox($string, "nonce3", $key);`

...

`$encrypted_X = sodium_crypto_secretbox($string, "nonceX", $key);`

This will produce different random values `$encrypted_1, $encrypted_2, $encrypted_3,..., $encrypted_X` that I can use for example in a cookie.

So far so good!

**An now the question:**

As all the encrypted values are based on the same `$string` and same `$key` Is it easy or nearly impossible to guess `$string` and `$key` on the basis of several encrypted values?

Comment: With a good encryption function you will not have any more information than you would with only one cyphertext. In effect using a different nonce means you are using a different key. With a badly designed encryption function, some information might leak.

Answer (score -1):

instead of encrypting same string seven times try to encrypt the encrypted string again like the following way.

```
$encrypted_1 = sodium_crypto_secretbox($string, "nonce1", $key);

$encrypted_2 = sodium_crypto_secretbox($encrypted_1 , "nonce2", $key);

$encrypted_3 = sodium_crypto_secretbox($encrypted_2, "nonce3", $key);
```

and so on. It will make it difficult to decrypt the value.